# Wordpress pagination_links not showing up at all?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination for past events, but I can't get it to work correctly.
Following a 2017 course on Wordpress, so it might just be outdated.

I have:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$pastEvents = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '<',
        'value' => $today,
        'type' => 'numeric',
        ),
    )
));
```

And my pagination on the bottom.

```
echo paginate_links(array(
    'total' => $pastEvents->max_num_pages,
));
```

I've looked online but can't find any way to fix it, personally. I was hoping to find an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be a typo in your WP_Query argument. Instead of `post_per_page`, it should be `posts_per_page`. Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$pastEvents = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // Corrected parameter name
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'compare' => '<',
            'value' => $today,
            'type' => 'numeric',
        ),
    )
));

// Your loop to display events

echo paginate_links(array(
    'total' => $pastEvents->max_num_pages,
));
```